# HTML support for column formatting using GWT?

Tags: html, css, gwt

In GWT I am using the following CSS to apply a format:

```
.watchListHeader {
  background-color: #2062B8;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Here is what I get when I apply the format in two different ways.

```
stocksFlexTable.getColumnFormatter().addStyleName(0, "watchListHeader");
```

[alt text http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/3958/columnformat.png](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/3958/columnformat.png)

```
stocksFlexTable.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(0, "watchListHeader");
```

[alt text http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/4986/rowformat.png](http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/4986/rowformat.png)

Here is a link to the [JavaDocs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html).
Under ColumnFormatter it briefly mentions limitations... does this mean this is expected behavior?  Seems to me formatting by column is nearly useless if I can't even format the text! Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: What exactly do you need here? I don't get what you want to achieve.

Comment: In the example above you can see applying the CSS to the column does not change the text but applies the background.  When applied to the row it works properly.  Is there an easy way to get this to work correctly with columns or do I have to apply the formatting to each individual cell in that column possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my question.  It is detailed very well at the following site. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html

In summary:

- In general row formatting overrides column formatting
- W3C specifies that only border, background, width and visibility may can be used. **Exception**: IE7 and lower allow all declarations.
- Background color and width are the only two that are fully supported across browsers and not quirky.